# Meaning of “a lot of ifs and buts”

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms

I was applying for a job in Ireland and I got this reply from this lady saying:

> Ok! But if you get the job & take it- You will be in Ireland! A lot of if & buts!

I did not understand what *a lot of ifs and buts* means?

Comment: [Ifs and buts](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/no-ifs-ands-or-buts?q=no+ifs+or+buts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She is referring to the list of many conditions that have to be satisfied before you start the job ... If you are shortlisted, if you are interviewed, if you are offered the job, if you accept it. Even then, she reminds you with her *but* that you will be in Ireland, not where you are now. *A lot of ifs and buts* emphasises to you that these conditions must be satisfied and that the end result would be that you live in Ireland.